# Multiple AUTH in one flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am new in flutter. just wanna know that is there any possible way to have multiple Auth project in one flutter app?
for my project， if i wanted to create a user login and admin login both data will store separately but in a single flutter app.  Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if a user can sign in to multiple Firebase projects with Firebase Authentication from a single Flutter app, the answer is yes.

You'll need to create a separate `FirebaseApp` object for each project, which contains the configuration data for that project. Then you create a `FirebaseAuth` instance for the specific `FirebaseApp`, and from there on you can call the same methods as always on the secondary `FirebaseAuth` object.

Also see:

- the FlutterFire documentation on [creating secondary Firebase apps](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage/#secondary-firebase-apps).
- the FlutterFire documentation on using Firebase Authentication, which contains an example of getting the auth instance with `FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp)`.